# In Spark, how do you read parquet files that were written with bucketBy, and preserve the bucketing data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

In Apache Spark 2.4.5, how do you open up a set of parquet files that were written with bucketBy and saveAsTable?

For example:

```
case class VeryVeryDeeplyNestedThing(
  s: String,
  nested1: OtherVeryDeeplyNestedThing
)
case class OtherVeryDeeplyNestedThing (
  youGetTheIdeaNoOneWantsToHandWriteASqlStatementForThese: NestedMcNesty
)
List(VeryVeryDeeplyNestedThing(...)).toDS()
  .write
  .bucketBy(512, "s")
  .option("path", "/tmp/output")
  .format("parquet")
  .saveAsTable("mytable")
```

Now there's a set of parquet files in `/tmp/output`.  Move the files in /tmp/output to /tmp/newPlace, and start a completely new spark session.

```
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/newPlace")
  .whatGoesHere?
```

What do you need to do to read them back in with the same bucketing information that they were written with?  It doesn't seem like that information is baked into the parquet files themselves, or is that what happens?

[Edit: added worked example partially from https://kb.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data/bucketing-example.html per @thebluephantom I think showing that reading does in fact require something special]

If you create the parquet files like this:

```
scala> def base = spark.range(1, 160000, 1, 16).select($"id" as "key", rand(12) as "value")
base: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

scala> base.write.format("parquet").bucketBy(16, "key").sortBy("value").option("path", "/tmp/example").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("bucketed")

scala> base.write.format("parquet").option("path", "/tmp/exampleunbucketed").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("unbucketed")

scala> val t2 = spark.table("bucketed")
t2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: bigint, value: double]

scala> val t3 = spark.table("bucketed")
t3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: bigint, value: double]

// This is joining two bucketed tables

scala> t3.join(t2, Seq("key")).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [key#51L, value#52, value#58]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [key#51L], [key#57L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [key#51L, value#52]
   :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(key#51L)
   :     +- *(2) FileScan parquet default.bucketed[key#51L,value#52] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ip-172-31-66-61.ec2.internal:50070/tmp/example], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(key)], ReadSchema: struct<key:bigint,value:double>, SelectedBucketsCount: 16 out of 16
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, true]))
      +- *(1) Project [key#57L, value#58]
         +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(key#57L)
            +- *(1) FileScan parquet default.bucketed[key#57L,value#58] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ip-172-31-66-61.ec2.internal:50070/tmp/example], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(key)], ReadSchema: struct<key:bigint,value:double>, SelectedBucketsCount: 16 out of 16
```

That has a `FileScan parquet default.bucketed` on both sides.  Now just do a plain read of the parquet files, and explain the join:

```
scala> val t4 = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/example")
t4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: bigint, value: double]

scala> t3.join(t4, Seq("key")).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [key#51L, value#52, value#64]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [key#51L], [key#63L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [key#51L, value#52]
   :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(key#51L)
   :     +- *(2) FileScan parquet default.bucketed[key#51L,value#52] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ip-172-31-66-61.ec2.internal:50070/tmp/example], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(key)], ReadSchema: struct<key:bigint,value:double>, SelectedBucketsCount: 16 out of 16
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, true]))
      +- *(1) Project [key#63L, value#64]
         +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(key#63L)
            +- *(1) FileScan parquet [key#63L,value#64] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ip-172-31-66-61.ec2.internal:50070/tmp/example], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(key)], ReadSchema: struct<key:bigint,value:double>
```

t4 doesn't have anything indicating that it's bucketed.

Does this matter?  Is it still bucketed?  Am I misreading the explain output?  Or do I have to do something to make sure t4 uses buckets?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: All works my side as expected. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. bucketBy is a table-based API, that simple.

Use bucket by so as to subsequently sort the tables and make subsequent `JOINs` faster by obviating shuffling. Use, thus for ETL for temporary, intermediate results processing in general.

Reading requires nothing special is added to the query, but the JOINed tables must BOTH be bucketed and have same number of buckets and partitions. See this excellent post: https://kb.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data/bucketing-example.html. Also, spark sql shuffle partitions must equal number of buckets.

**UPDATE**

In case of small data the broadcast hash join may occur, so set the following:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.bucketing.enabled", true)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
```

Also, use `spark.table` I suggest, not `spark.read.parquet...` bucketBy ony works with table api. See https://blog.taboola.com/bucket-the-shuffle-out-of-here/

Comment: I did see that post, but it's part of what made me ask the question.  They're definitely doing something special in every case when they're reading; they never start from just parquet files.  I'll add more info to my question.

Comment: Nothing goes there though.

Comment: Use bucket by to sort the tables and make subsequent joins faster. It does a sort and pertains to a JOIN situation subsequently. The catalyst optimizer sees that and need not shuffle. As you see in  the docs there is nothing special to do.

Comment: The whole idea of bucketing is simply to prepare the data for shuffle-less queries.

Comment: May well be that you have no use case if you do not need shuffleless query.

Comment: You are certainly persistent. I cannot state other than what the intended afaik purpose is.

Comment: I have some very large joins that I think will benefit from bucketing.  Hopefully my example that I added will make the question more clear.

Comment: Sir, the question is clear to me. I will look after din dins.

Comment: they both have to be bucketed so as to avoid a shuffle. Only 1 is bucketed and hence the shuffling occurs - as you see.

Comment: Right, so the question is how do you take those parquet files and turn them into something that _is_ bucketed.

Comment: I am seeing that things have changed a little, I am looking now. I am using a DB Community which is small. I would use spark.table as a matter of, but I just re-ran the blurb and got also now this issue. I will get back.

Comment: Updated answer. All there. Success.

Answer (score 0):

When we use bucketing or clustering while writing the data it divides the data save as multiple files.
For Ex:

```
id,name,city
1,a,CA
2,b,NYC
3,c,NYC
4,d,CA

#So after bucketing based on city two file will be created 
id,name,city
1,a,CA
4,d,CA

and
id,name,city
2,b,NYC
3,c,NYC
```

SO when we read the file from new location we will be able to read the whole data.

Bucketing helps when you want to predicate pushdown some conditions as it will restrict spark to read only the specific files.

Hope it answers.

Comment: I added more information to the question.  I'm asking about how to use bucketing, not why.